# nested JSON variable

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON output as follows: http://pastebin.com/yrbdSrMd I now wish to find the **name** of a **page not the name of a rune**

```
$decode_runes = json_decode($summoner_runes);
```

things i have tried:

```
$r = $decode_runes->{'name'};
```

and

```
$r = $decode_runes->{'pages.name'};
```

to work with this if statement:

```
if($r==$verify_code) {echo "successful!<br><br>";}
else {echo "unsuccessful!<br><br>";}
```

Comment: Use [json_decode](http://in2.php.net/json_decode) to decode json string & than access it.

Comment: that is what i've done - updated answer with decode - code

Comment: Your json seems to be in incorrect format. Add `cho json_last_error();` after json_decode code to check error.

Comment: League of Legends huh?

Comment: @RubenSerrate Indeed!

Comment: @Rikesh `cho json_last_error();` just gives a line error.

Comment: Can you tell us if a rune with a given id can be in several pages at the same time ?

Comment: @aduch an id is unique, but you can't calculate what ID the page will be - thats why I am trying to get the name

Comment: @Night - I mean `echo json_last_error();`.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it to work!

```
            $grab_data = $instance->getSummonerByName($summoner_name);
            $decode_data = json_decode($grab_data);
            $grab_id = $decode_data->{'id'};
            var_dump($grab_id);
            $grab_runes = $instance->getSummoner($grab_id,'runes');
            print_r($grab_runes);
            $decode_runes = json_decode($grab_runes);
            $rune_check = $decode_runes->{'name'};

            if ($rune_check = $verify_code) {echo 'kappa';}
            else {echo 'error';}
```